# How to specify cells in csv file with certain conditions in R

Tags: r, csv, event-log

I have an event log in csv format and want to specify cells with certain condition in the table. The table looks like below.

```
Case.ID | Activity | Timestamp | Resource
----------------------------------------------
   0    |Take order| 00:12:04  |  Waiter
----------------------------------------------
   0    |Take order| 00:18:02  |
----------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food| 00:47:23  | Cook helper
----------------------------------------------
   1    |Bring food| 00:52:41  |
```

Start of the activity has value in Resource column, but end of the activity has none in there.

I want to make a column duration, which is the difference from end timestamp to start timestamp but not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: `aggregate` by Case.ID with the function `difftime` on column Timestamp.

Comment: what class is your Timestamp col?

Comment: @timfaber It is a factor now

Comment: @R.Schifini You mean `aggregate(csv, by=list(csv$Case.ID), FUN=difftime(Complete.Timestamp))` ?

Comment: Add to the post some sample data using `dput`. Your example is very hard to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data frame given by @timfaber  do:

```
aggregate(x = list(duration = as.POSIXct(df$Timestamp,format = "%H:%M:%S")),
          by = list(Case.ID = df$Case.ID),
          FUN = diff)
```

This gives:

```
  Case.ID  duration
1       0 5.966667 
2       1 5.300000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you coerce your factor to be a character variable you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(Case.ID = c(0,0,1,1),
            Activity = c(rep("Take order",2),rep("Bring food",2)),
            Timestamp = c("00:12:04","00:18:02","00:47:23","00:52:41"),
            Resource = c("Waiter","","Cook helper",""),stringsAsFactors = F)



df %>% group_by(Case.ID) %>% mutate(timing = as.difftime(Timestamp[length(Timestamp)])-as.difftime(Timestamp[1]))
```

Not so elegant since it recycles the values over rows but I am not sure what you are aiming at